# Windows 8: connected to the Wi-fi but not loading any page

Tags: windows-8, internet, connection

I had a problem with the internet over the last 2 days, I fixed it thanks to this network (some information around) and wanted to make a little thread to help future users with my same problem.

### Specifications

OS: Windows 8.1
Internet connection: Wi-fi
Installed anti-virus: KasperSky and McAfee Security Scan Plus

### Problem

Internet shows to be correctly connected.

[image]

The Wi-fi is working, other devices are connected to the same router and working fine.
However, loading any page on any browser is impossible. Nor Dropbox is showing any loading signal.

### Behavior when resetting connection

1. Disconnecting from the network
2. Reconnecting to the network
3. Connection is limited
4. Click on troubleshooting: even before the tool starts running, connection is back. But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps, very easy but found a bit around in the web, worked perfectly.

1. Uninstall the McAfee Security Scan Plus from my computer;
2. Restarting the computer.

I found a similar answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/497458/399672), and it was actually the one giving me the solution. But the OP forgot to add the application he uninstalled, and probably it was not even the same.

So, here I leave my small contribution to a very simple problem that I've tried to troubleshoot in several ways over the last 2 days, when the solution was so simple.

Comment: McAfee is considered malware. Software has sucked since 2002.